# Java Springboot container connecting to oracle database container

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

While connecting to a container with oracle database.

I have made a container using
`docker run -it --rm -p 1522:1522 -e ORACLE_PASSWORD=oracle --name=oracle --network=my-network gvenzl/oracle-xe:21`

Container is working well, but when i try to connect using springboot application it refuses to connect giving error:

> Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource
> org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not
> get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is
> org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to
> obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is
> java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: The Network Adapter could not
> establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=Jgeu+rxZRACc21FmuU1HZA==)

Im using `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@oracle:1522/xe`

Also using docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  ca-manager:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - my-network
networks:
  my-network:
    external: true
```

I'm getting the error:

> java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could
> not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=fg

Changing docker-compose, urls

Answer (score 1):

With the following configuration, my spring boot app can successfully connect to the oracle server using the URL *jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522/xe*.

*docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3'
services:
  oracle-xe:
    image: gvenzl/oracle-xe:21
    ports:
      - "1522:1521"
    environment:
      - ORACLE_PASSWORD=oracle
    networks:
      - oracle
networks:
  oracle:
    name: oracle
```

*pomx.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>oraclespring</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>oraclespring</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

*application.properties*

```
# Spring Boot Config for Oracle
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1522/xe
spring.datasource.username=system
spring.datasource.password=oracle
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
#hibernate config
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
```

Comment: I have changed it into one docker-compose file, but this url which you are provided is still not working correctly
version: '3'
services:
  oracle-xe:
    image: gvenzl/oracle-xe:21
    ports:
      - 1522:1521
    environment:
      - ORACLE_PASSWORD=oracle
    volumes:
      - ../database/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  manager:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:8080